# animate.css is not working with some classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, animate.css

Please help me to animate this element on mouse over with animate.css and javascript(jQuery)

This is what I have tried, but not working with some classes eg.  `animate__jello`

**HTML**

```
 <span onmouseover="add_efect(this)" > Eat </span>
```

**JS**

```
function add_efect(element){
  element.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__jello');
  
  element.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  element.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__jello');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `<span>` element with animate.css you need to add `display:inline-block` to it or you can change it with `<h6>` as you see in below.

`<span>` elements can't be animated with animate.CSS. To animate them, you will need to give them a display property.

```js
function add_efect(element){
  element.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__jello');
  
  element.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  element.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__jello');
  });
}
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />

<h6 onmouseover="add_efect(this)">Eat</h6>


<span style='display:inline-block;' onmouseover="add_efect(this)"> Drink </span>
```